# Programa sobre Progressão Aritimética usando tkinter

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, loop, matemática, tkinter

estava fazendo um programa que resolva uma P.A utilizando interfaces gráficas usando tkinter porem venho recebendo um erro recorrente que não sei solucionar:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1475, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\Michel\Desktop\Python prog 2\Progressão aritmética com tkinter.py", line 56, in aoclicarok1
self.an = int(self.a1.get()) + int(self.r.get()) * int(self.razao.get())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

alguem podeira ajudar?

meu código:

entry_config = {
"width": "18",
"relief": "sunken",
"bd": "3",
"font": ("Geometr212 BkCn BT", 17),
"fg": "#000000",
"bg": "#ffffff"
}

label_config = {
"font":("Geometr212 BkCn BT",12)
}

botao_config = {
"bg":"#758ebf",
"fg":"#000000",
"font":("Geometr212 BkCn BT",12),
"height": "2",
"width": "7",
"relief": "raised",
"activebackground":"#e3a724"
}

class pa:

```
def __init__(self, master):
     
    self.master = master
    #label de texto
    lab = tk.Label(self.master, label_config, text = "Defina o termo na posição 1: ")
    lab.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
      
    lab1 = tk.Label(self.master, label_config, text = "Defina a razão: ")
    lab1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            
    lab2 = tk.Label(self.master, label_config, text = "Quantidade de termos a serem exibidos: ")
    lab2.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    #entrada de dados
    self.a1 = tk.Entry(self.master, entry_config)
    self.a1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    self.razao = tk.Entry(self.master, entry_config)
    self.razao.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    self.n = tk.Entry(self.master, entry_config)    
    self.n.grid(row = 2, column = 1)        
    #botão
    bot = tk.Button(self.master, botao_config, text = "ok", command = self.aoclicarok1)
    bot.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

def aoclicarok1(self):

    self.r = int(self.n.get()) - 1
    self.an = int(self.a1.get()) + int(self.r.get()) * int(self.razao.get())
    self.an = int((self.an.get()) + 1)

    while True:
        try:
        
            lab = tk.Label(self.master, label_config, text = self.an)
            lab.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

        except EOFError:
            break
```

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Progressão aritmética")
pa(root)
root.mainloop()

Comment: já resolvi  o problema.

Answer (score 0):

o problema é que você faz:

```
self.an = int(self.a1.get()) + int(self.r.get()) * int(self.razao.get())
```

então `an` é inteiro. Depois na linha seguinte você faz `self.an.get()` e números inteiro não funcionam com `.get()`. Você concertaria simplesmente trocando `self.an = int((self.an.get()) + 1)` por `self.an += 1`